# Meaning of pathname "." using ftok()

Tags: c, linux, ipc, sysv-ipc

I came across the [following program](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/shm/example-2.html) to implement a shared memory IPC between a client and a server.

The following line is used to generate a unique sysv key (as mentioned [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftok.3.html)):

```
ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x');
```

What does a pathname "." mean in this case?
I am completely new to linux and a clear-cut answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that the current directory is not necessarily the path where the executable file is saved.

Comment: if you do `ls -a` in a shell you'll see the directories `.` and `..`. Every directory has them,, `.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pathname "." means the current directory.  You can find more details of function [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftok.3.html) Or executing command `man ftok` in your Linux machine.